# Container JVM CPU monitoring

Tags: spring-boot, docker, jvm

I want to monitor the JVM's CPU on a container basis.
I tried collecting through the actuator, but the values ​​don't seem to match, so I'm looking for another method.
Is there any way to collect the JVM CPU? It would be nice to know how the limit is also set.

thank you :)